# Change UITextView scrollbar color

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollbar, uitextview

I have a ViewController that contains an UITextView.Is there any way to change colour of TextView's scroll bar? I want to achieve this in red rectangle:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Might be that helpful but not sure: https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar

Comment: @NitinGohel thanks for your answer.I'll check this and i will let you know!

Comment: @NitinGohel Have you ever used this project? I imported it to my project and i assign BRScrollBar to my textView but the problem is that the scrollbar appears right to the basic view and not in the position of my textView.Have you any idea how to change the position of scrollBar? Thanks.

Comment: no buddy i never used this project i just found and given link to you. check it's class might you can find something.

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone has the same problem in the future here is one way to solve this:

**1)** Import the project from Github that Nitin suggested.
[BRScrollBar](https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar)

**2)** In BRScrollBarController.h file change this line

```
+ (id)initForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView inPosition:(BRScrollBarPostions)position 
           delegate:(id<BRScrollBarControllerDelegate>)delegate;
```

to this line

```
+ (id)initForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView inPosition:(BRScrollBarPostions)position inPositionPoint:(CGPoint) lala
           delegate:(id<BRScrollBarControllerDelegate>)delegate;
```

**3)** In BRScrollBarController.m file

*a)* Add this variable

```
CGPoint positionPoint;
```

exactly below declaration of *_instance variable

*b)* Change this line

```
+ (id)initForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView inPosition:(BRScrollBarPostions)position 
           delegate:(id<BRScrollBarControllerDelegate>)delegate
```

to this line

```
+ (id)initForScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView inPosition:(BRScrollBarPostions)position inPositionPoint:(CGPoint) lala
           delegate:(id<BRScrollBarControllerDelegate>)delegate
```

and also add this line to the beginning of this method

```
     positionPoint=lala;
```

*c)* In method initScrollBarViewForPostion remove line

```
    CGPoint origin = [self scrollBarOriginForPosition:position];
```

and replace origin with positionPoint.

**4)** In your ViewController.h file:

*a)* Import BRScrollBarController.h file

*b)* Add this delegate BRScrollBarControllerDelegate

*c)* Add this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) BRScrollBarController *brScrollBarController;
```

**5)** Finally in your ViewController.m file that you want to use this scroll bar add these in viewDidLoad method:

```
 CGPoint lala=CGPointMake(self.articleDescription.frame.origin.x+self.articleDescription.frame.size.width, self.monumentTitle.frame.origin.y+self.monumentTitle.frame.size.height-25);


_brScrollBarController = [BRScrollBarController initForScrollView:self.articleDescription
                                                       inPosition:kIntBRScrollBarPositionRight inPositionPoint:lala
                                                         delegate:self];




_brScrollBarController.scrollBar.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
```

With lala variable you can move your scrollbar everywhere.

Also you can change the background colour to everything you want.